# Is there any globally unique indentifier for a song purchased from iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, avaudioplayer

i am creating an Music iPhone application using AVAudioPlayer and in this i am using the songs from the iPod library and keeping songs in the server after some sorting. I want to know is there any unique identifier to identify a song that purchased from iTunes store? Not locally, I meant globally unique identifier. And also I want to add a download button in the app, for directly downloading the song directly from iTunes store? Should we manually create the link? Or is there any alternative way?

Please help

Comment: All iTunes Store-items have an identifier called `AdamID`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but how can I get this AdamID of a song?

Comment: Any updates on this? AdamID is not in any API reference... Uh except here: https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/introduction---search-api.html :-)

Comment: Ok after some more research it appears that "adam id" is the same as apple id, and it might be named differently at other times. It seems to simply be the ids you would specify in a lookup api call etc. It could be an artist or album or something else in the iTunes Store. For example '74576999' id points to an artist: https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=74576999 For me I am trying to match single tracks, but am not sure if single tracks have ids or not. Even with the search API I haven't found any consistent ID so far for tracks.

Comment: Any updates? Quite interesting question.